# boto 3 - EC2 Linux instance - need to capture device name as variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, device-name

I need to capture variable value for Linux EC2 instances.

```
'Name': 'device',
'Value': "xvdg"
```

The value Disk Name(device name) changes for EC2 Linux instances e.g `sdh`,`xvdg`, etc..

I am using boto3 SDK

Any help is much appreciated.

Current Code (Hard coded the Device Name):

```
cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm(
  AlarmName=prefix +  ' -  Elastic Search Disc % Availabilty is less than the configured threshold value - Please increase size of EBS Volume',
  ComparisonOperator='LowerThanThreshold',
  EvaluationPeriods=3,
  MetricName='disk_used_percent',
  Namespace='CWAgent',
  Period=300,
  Statistic='Average',
  Threshold=75,
  AlarmActions=[snstopicarn],
  AlarmDescription='Standard Disc Alert - Elastic Search Disc % Availabilty is less than the configured threshold value - Please increase size of EBS Volume',
  Dimensions=[
                            {
                              'Name': 'InstanceId',
                              'Value': instance["InstanceId"]
                            },

                            {
                              'Name': 'path',
                              'Value': "/mnt/elasticsearch"
                            },
                            {
                              'Name': 'device',
                              'Value': "xvdi"
                            },
                            {
                              'Name': 'fstype',
                              'Value': "ext4"
                            },
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `describe_instances` and extract `DeviceName`. ([boto3 doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances))

```py
import boto3

instance_id = <instance_id>

client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances(
    InstanceIds=[
        instance_id,
    ],
)

device_name = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['BlockDeviceMappings'][0]['DeviceName']

#/dev/xvda
print(device_name)
```

---

When using `describe_alarms_for_metric`, the code would be like this.

```
response = client.describe_alarms_for_metric(
    MetricName='string',
    Namespace='string',
    Statistic='SampleCount'|'Average'|'Sum'|'Minimum'|'Maximum',
    ExtendedStatistic='string',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ],
    Period=123,
    Unit='Seconds'|'Microseconds'|'Milliseconds'|'Bytes'|'Kilobytes'|'Megabytes'|'Gigabytes'|'Terabytes'|'Bits'|'Kilobits'|'Megabits'|'Gigabits'|'Terabits'|'Percent'|'Count'|'Bytes/Second'|'Kilobytes/Second'|'Megabytes/Second'|'Gigabytes/Second'|'Terabytes/Second'|'Bits/Second'|'Kilobits/Second'|'Megabits/Second'|'Gigabits/Second'|'Terabits/Second'|'Count/Second'|'None'
)
```

```
response = cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm(....)

for i in response['MetricAlarms'][0]['Dimensions'][0]:
    if i['Name'] == 'device':
        print(i['Value'])  # xvdi
```

Comment: hi @shimo thank you for the details. Well what I actually need is to get the "Device" Variable for "cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm" Dimensions=[ {'Name': 'Device','Value': "xvdi"}]              
how i get 'device' with boto3.   describe_instances can extract DeviceName however it does not work for cloudwatch.put.metric. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm returns None. Using describe_alarms_for_metric might work. Updated but not confirmed myself.

Comment: `code`  response = cloudwatch.describe_alarms_for_metric(MetricName='Device', Namespace='CWAgent',Statistic='Average',Period=300 ,Unit='Megabytes',Dimensions=[{                        'Name': 'Device',
                          'Value': "Device"
                       },],
                  )
                    for i in response['MetricAlarms'][0]['Dimensions'][0]:
                         if i['Name'] == 'Device':
                          print(i['Value'])

Comment: `code`cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm(,ComparisonOperator='LessThanThreshold',EvaluationPeriods=3,MetricName='disk_used_percent',Namespace='CWAgent',Period=300,Statistic='Average',Threshold=1,AlarmActions=[snstopicarn],Dimensions=[
{'Name': 'InstanceId','Value': instance["InstanceId"]},
{'Name': 'path','Value': "/mnt/elasticsearch"},
                            { 'Name': 'Device',
                              'Value': 'Device'
                            },
                            {'Name': 'fstype',
                              'Value': "ext4"},])

Comment: I am getting following error "Dynamic Creation of CloudWatch Alerts for AWS Servers  is Failed . Exception : list index out of range" any pointers is much appreciated, thanks.